# ASP.NET: How to change the itemTemplate used per row in an <asp:repeater>?

Tags: asp.net

*Existing* code is using an `asp:repeater` to build an HTML table. (emphasis on the existing design). This is some partial pseudo-code to generate the table:

```
<asp:repeater OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound" ... >

   <headertemplate>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td>Date</td>
               <td>Type</td>
               <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
         </thread>
   </headertemplate>

   <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
         <td><%# GetTextForThis((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
         <td><%# GetTextForThat((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
         <td><%# GetTextForTheOther((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>

   <footertemplate>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </footertemplate>

</asp:repeater>
```

But now it is needed that (some) items display differently, and it is needed that it is done using a `COLSPAN=3`, and the entire item will be one cell:

```
   <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
            <img src="<%# GetImageSrcForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
            <a href="<%# GetHrefForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
```

Given:

- the page uses a repeater to build an HTML table
- the design requires some table rows to span columns

How can i do this?

i was **hoping** for something like:

```
   <itemtemplate id="thisThatTheOtherItemTemplate">
      <tr>
         <td><%# GetTextForThis((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
         <td><%# GetTextForThat((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
         <td><%# GetTextForTheOther((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>


   <itemtemplate id="fooItemTemplate">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
            <img src="<%# GetImageSrcForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
            <a href="<%# GetHrefForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
```

and somehow magically be able to have the OnDataBind event tell the repeater which template to use. Is this possble?

### Answer

Although both answers are right and good, i'd rather use the first suggestion; which involves having display code in the aspx file, rather than building HTML manually in a code-behind. (i don't want to ever have to build HTML in code again)

```
   <itemtemplate>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="thing1" runat="server">
         <tr>
            <td><%# GetTextForThis((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
            <td><%# GetTextForThat((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
            <td><%# GetTextForTheOther((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %></td>
         </tr>
      </asp:PlaceHolder>

      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="thing2" visible="false" runat="server">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
               <img src="<%# GetImageSrcForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
               <a href="<%# GetHrefForFoo((MyItem)Container.DataItem) %>
            </td>
         </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   // if the data bound item is an item or alternating item (not the header etc)
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      // get the associated object
      Object item = .Item.DataItem;
      if (item == null)
         return;

      Control thing1 = e.Item.FindControl("thing1");
      Control thing2 = e.Item.FindControl("thing2");

      if (item is MyClassThatICreated)
      {
         thing1.Visible = false;
         thing2.Visible = true;
      }
      else
      {
         thing1.Visible = true;
         thing2.Visible = false;
      }
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place two ASP:Placeholder controls in your item template. In the codebehind, on the ItemDataBound event, determine which style you want to show, and hide one placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Jonathan's suggestion is to just dynamically build the item on the backend in the ItemDataBound event, some people find that easier to work with, rather than toggling visibility.

I personally in this case would just put a literal in, with mode="Passthrough" and would build it on the backend.

Comment: I would have done what jonathon suggested, but I think this is the better way to handle it, +1