# asp button created using c# isn't showing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I created an asp:Button in MyAdoHelperSQL.cs which is supposed to appear in adminRiddles.aspx, but this button just isn't showing up. If I open the "Inspect" option while running the code in Google Chrome, I can see that this button **does exist** in the code, but it isn't showing up.
I also created in the adminRiddles.aspx another button with the exact same code (just for checking), and this one is visible.
What's the problem? 
 How can I fix it?

code: 
**MyAdoHelperSQL.cs**

```
string printStr = "<div class='riddles'> <table>";
printStr += "<tr> <td> <asp:Button id='add"+idNum+ "' style='float:right; display:block;' runat='server' Text='confirm' Width='70px' OnClick='add_Click'></asp:button> </td> </tr> </table> </div>";
return printStr;
```

**adminRiddles.aspx** uses a c# function to call the MyAdoHelperSQL.cs above and prints the *printstr* string into a form.

 This is the code of the working button:

```
    <form runat="server">
                <div class='riddles'>
                    <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td> 
        <asp:Button id='Button2' style='float:right; display:block;' runat='server' Text='confirm' Width='70px' OnClick='add_Click'></asp:button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: See these Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+add+control+button+%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1

Comment: @rene I think that it isn't my problem. I just can't see my button, just because it was created in c#.

Comment: If you create a string with that asp:Button and then have adminRiddles.aspx write that string to your output stream you for sure have that problem. Your own diagnosis confirms that.

Comment: @rene I afraid I didn't get you. What problem are you talking about?
Also, can you link me to a specific Q/A and not for search page?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, let me do all the research. Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10397856/578411 and here is the tuned search in case you need some more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+add+button+codebehind+%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A1+-%22user+control%22

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me so much, because I'm using an external c# class called MyAdoHelperSQL.cs, which using my DB table. The table updates all the time, so everything related to the table should be dynamic.

Comment: Your helper class should return the data, preferable in a databindable collection, for example a datatable so you can use  a repeater control and ItemTemplates to build the View from your data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869237 You don't have all these data binding goodies if you keep muddling with strings that contains markup. It is unfixable based on what you've currently shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject an asp control like that as raw text, this would work with raw HTML but not with a control the server side needs to know about.

The best approach would be to add this control dynamically as an actual control:

**adminRiddles.aspx:** Give the table row and td an ID and set to runat="server"

```
<div class='riddles' id="riddlesdiv" runat="server">
<table id="riddlestable" runat="server">
    <tr id="riddlestr" runat="server">
        <td id="riddlestd" runat="server">      
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**adminRiddles.aspx.cs:** Add the control in code

```
Button addButton = new Button();
addButton.ID = "add" + idNum;
addButton.Text = "confirm";
addButton.Click += add_Click;
riddlestd.Controls.Add(addButton);
```

If you have multiple rows you may need to take this a stage further and dyamically add both table rows and their content.

Comment: Looks helpful, but I have a dynamic number of TRs and TDs.
This page shows data from a table which the website's users send to it.
How can I do it?
It means every td has to have a unique id, etc.

Comment: I mean I can't do what you wrote here, because I'm using an external c# class called MyAdoHelperSQL.cs, which using my DB table. The table updates all the time, so I need to be ready to changes...

Comment: I mentioned taking it a stage futher & adding rows and their content and buttons dynamically too. Get your AdoHelperSQL.cs class to return the dataset (or whatever you're bringing back from the database) back to adminRiddles.aspx.cs (i.e. call it from there). Then loop through each record in the dataset adding a new tr, td, content & button controls to the table in the way described in the answer. This answer describes how to do this equivilent with tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789240/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-table-in-asp-net/3789358

Comment: I would suggest using a repeater for this - that's what its for. No need then to try and inject buttons and actions etc. into a page. Such solutions are messy at best, and worse hooking up events etc. is painful. If you need to repeat something, use a repeater - it has that name for a reason.